# Do the sentences "I am not here to advocate woman suffrage. American suffragists can do that themselves." contain a rhetorical strategy?

Tags: rhetoric

I had to shorten it in the title, but, Emmeline Pankhurst begins her "Freedom or Death" speech with,

"Tonight I am not here to advocate woman suffrage. American suffragists can do that very well for themselves."

Is this a rhetorical strategy or am I thinking too hard? The only thing that comes to mind is an oxymoron, but I believe that is only used for a short phrase, while this is two sentences.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're overthinking it. Emmeline Pankhurst, a person from England, was in the United States when she gave that speech. For those two lines together, she was saying "I could talk about these things, but there are capable locals who can do that for you."